# Creating a table in ORACLE will not insert sample row because of error

Tags: oracle

```
 CREATE TABLE MSALE
 (SaleNo INTEGER, 
 SaleQuantity INTEGER,
 ItemName varchar(200),
 LineItem1 varchar(200), 
 LineItem2 varchar(200), 
 LineItem3 varchar(200),
 DeptName varchar(15),
 DatesOfSales DATE,
 Cust_ID INTEGER,
 Address varchar(100),
 City varchar(100),
 State NUMBER(2),
 Zip NUMBER(5));
INSERT INTO MSALE(SALENO, SALEQUANTITY, 
ITEMNAME, LINEITEM1, LINEITEM2,          
LINEITEM3, DEPTNAME, DATESOFSALES, CUST_ID,ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP)
 VALUES(1111, 3, 'sextant, compass, map case', 'sextant', 
 'compass', 'map case', 'recreation', TO_DATE('2014 01 01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
 1, '1332 Southern Drive', 'Statesboro', 'GA', 30458);
```

Error seen is below:

```
table MSALE created.
Error starting at line : 265 in command -
INSERT INTO MSALE(SALENO, SALEQUANTITY, ITEMNAME, LINEITEM1, LINEITEM2, LINEITEM3, DEPTNAME, DATESOFSALES, CUST_ID,ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP)
VALUES(1111, 3, 'sextant, compass, map case', 'sextant', 'compass', 'map case', 'recreation', TO_DATE('2014 01 01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
1, '1332 Southern Drive', 'Statesboro', 'GA', 30458)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State is a number field, but you're entering text, 'GA'. It's a weird error message, but that might be it.